# How to change browser mode in IE9 permanently?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

How can I change the browser mode in IE9 permanently, like for example to IE7?

Currently, this change is only temporary and whenever you open a new window, you have to go to the developer mode to switch the settings again.

Clarification: "Windows 7 requires you to run IE9. But for work purposes some people still need to use IE7 or IE8. Developer Tools enables a person to use IE7 settings with in IE9. But for each window that is opened it seems that everytime one has to go in developer mode to switch Browser mode to IE7. The question is how does one achieve the settings that will allow the IE9 to open up in IE7 mode everytime the browser is fired up."

Comment: Change it to what?

Comment: Change to other one of the available browser modes available. The question is not "change to what" but "make the change permanent".

Comment: I don't think anyone understand the question that is being asked.
Windows 7 requires you to run IE9. But for work purposes some people still need to use IE7 or IE8.
Developer Tools enables a person to use IE7 settings with in IE9. But for each window that is opened it seems that everytime one has to go in developer mode to switch Browser mode to IE7. The question is how does one achieve the settings that will allow the IE9 to open up in IE7 mode everytime the browser is fired up.

Comment: See? You got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this issue with `<meta x-ua-compatible />` element and providing it the ie7 variable.
Another alternative is to change the document mode using the `documentMode` property.
MSDN Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can really affect the browser mode setting; this seems to be a developer debugging feature. If a user is running IE9, the browser mode will be IE9 or IE9 Compatibility View. You can affect the compatibility view setting by using the X-UA-Compatible `<meta>` tag or HTTP header (though, watch out for the Tools -> Compatibility View settings - > "Display Intranet sites in Compatibility View" setting).

Answer (score 4):

I found a registry setting that can force IE9 to run in IE8 or IE7 in browser emulation mode permanently.  For example, to run IE9 in IE8 mode, add the follow key, value, and data to the registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Wow6432Node (for IE 32-bit on a 64-bit OS)
         Microsoft
            Internet Explorer
               Main
                  FeatureControl
                     FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                        iexplore.exe = (DWORD) 00008888
```

You can use decimal value 8000 for IE8, but is only applied if !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode.  Decimal value 8888 is for IE8 regardless of !DOCTYPE directives, which is why I chose in my example.

Decimal value 7000 is for IE7, but only applied if !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation

***Note:*** The developer toolbar will display "Browser Mode: unknown", so that is not a valid test.

Answer (score 2):

In the Group Policy Editor, under Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Compatibility View, there’s a setting for “Turn off Compatibility View” that can be set to Enabled, which will leave the browser in IE9 mode permanently.

Answer (score 1):

> - Developers can change Browser Mode through the “Browser Mode” menu in IE’s F12 Developer Tools. This setting only applies to the developer’s local machine. For example, developers can have IE9 emulate an IE7 browser, IE8 browser or IE9 in Compatibility View.

> [image: Select Browser Mode]

> - Users can change Browser Mode by clicking on the Compatibility View (CV) button, which causes IE8 and IE9 to emulate the IE7 browser. This is why it’s important for site developers to test their site in the Compatibility View Browser Mode.
> - IE’s Compat View List can also change the Browser Mode for specific sites.

From here:

- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode)

Comment: I know that. The problem is that the change is only temporary. I need to make it permanent on a certain browser's computer.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro i'm facing with the same problem. is there any luck to find solution ?

Comment: No mate, I didn't actually find a solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

What I do is install the Windows virtual machine with XP mode in Windows 7 (Professional). This is all free and on MS web site. Run the older browser of your choice under XP. If you want multiple browsers available, I believe you can install multiple instances of a virtual machine.

I run Office 2003 on the XP virtual machine as well. So I can have access to multiple versions of Office. The XP virtual machine is really XP, not some emulation of XP. The alternate XP environment is useful for other areas of testing too.

Answer (score 0):

i reckon that you are working on intranet links/servers
if so, Just one line answer to your question

Disable the compatibility view : Goto Tools >> compatibility view setting >> uncheck 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' (by default this checked)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is happening on a specific computer, then please try the following fix provided you have Internet Explorer 11.

Please open regedit.exe as an Administrator.
Navigate to the following path/paths:

1. For 32 bit machine:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`
2. For 64 bit machine:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

And delete the REG_DWORD value `iexplore.exe`.
Please close and relaunch the website using Internet Explorer 11, it will default to Edge as Document Mode.